# Running React-Native app on android shows "Object is not iterable"

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

[image: Object not iterable]

[image: JS debugger]

running react-native android app, gives this output on emulator. any Idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide us with more information?

Comment: Trying to set-up environment, gradle is building successfully on android studios, when i run the environment using npx react-native run-android, the emulator shows this output.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are fetching some data from API, so the object you are training to parse may have an attribute that is not list, so that means an object is not iterable. I'm also guessing that you are not using typescript, which helps with errors like this.

Comment: Try to comment your current code slowly, and run it again. after you narrow the area, you can post the code here. At least that's what I'm gonna do if facing some unknown errors.

Comment: i have posted the App.js file as answer, no idea from where i am facing the error. guide me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AppRegistry, Dimensions, ActivityIndicator, AsyncStorage, View, StyleSheet, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation"
import { createStackNavigator} from "react-navigation-stack";
import Ionicons from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";

//Components
import HomeScreen from "./app/screens/HomeScreen/homeScreen";
import MapScreen from "./app/screens/MapScreen/mapScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "./app/screens/ProfileScreen/profileScreen";
import LoginScreen from "./app/screens/LoginScreen/loginScreen";
import ChatListScreen from "./app/screens/ChatListScreen/chatListScreen";
import SignupScreen from "./app/screens/SignupScreen/signupScreen";
import NotificationScreen from "./app/screens/NotificationScreen/notificationScreen";
import ForgotPasswordScreen from "./app/screens/ForgotPasswordScreen/forgotPasswordScreen";
import NewPostScreen from "./app/screens/NewPostScreen/NewPostScreen";
import MessageScreen from "./app/screens/MessaginScreen/messaginScreen";
//Screen names
import { Home, Info, DetailView, Login } from "./app/screens/index";
//Screen size
var {height, width} = Dimensions.get("window");


class AuthLoadingScreen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._bootstrapAsync();
  }

  _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userToken");

    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? "Auth" : "Auth");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

const AppStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Messages : { screen: ChatListScreen },
    Map : { screen: MapScreen },
    Notifications : { screen: NotificationScreen },
    Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen }    
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === "Home") {
          iconName = "home";
        } else if (routeName === "Messages") {
          iconName = "comment";

        } else if (routeName === "Map") {
          iconName = "map";
        
        } else if (routeName === "Notifications") {
          iconName = "bell";
        
        } else if (routeName === "Profile") {
          iconName = "user";
        }
        return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#3d9bf9",
      inactiveTintColor: "gray",
    },
  }  
);

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
      Login:{
          screen:LoginScreen
      },
      Signup:{
          screen:SignupScreen
      },
      ForgotPassword:{
        screen:ForgotPasswordScreen
      },
      NewPost:{ 
        screen:NewPostScreen
      },
      MessageView:{ 
        screen:MessageScreen
      },
      App:{
        screen:AppStack
      }        
  },{
      initialRouteName:"Login", 
      mode: 'modal',       
      headerMode:"none"
  }
)

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AuthStack);
export default AppContainer;
```